# What should be the correct way in assigning value to a static variable?

Tags: java

I'm trying to initialize a variable within a class constructor but the IDE is showing this warning:

`The static field SoapClient.url should be accessed in a static way.`

Can you please check my code below? What should be the correct way to initialize the static variable? Should I ignore the warning or should I just make the variable non-static?

Thanks.

```
public class SoapClient {
    private static String url;

    public SoapClient(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to be `static`..?

Comment: Are you sure that each new instance of a `SoapClient` can change the static `url` field?

Comment: +1 for loving your cat.

Comment: Don't use static fields unless they are constants (i.e. `final`). Almost all other uses could be [considered evil](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a variable is `static`, this means that you'll have one `url` for all instances, and not per *object*. You don't want each construction of an object to change `url`. However, if you still want to do this, you can access it like `SoapClient.url`.

(In your code, `url` will always hold the value of the last constructed object).

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is the static way:

```
SoapClient.url = ""
```

But here you probably need a regular field:

```
public class SoapClient {
    private final String url;

    public SoapClient(final String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That warning comes out of accessing the variable url through the this. variable, which refers to the current instance of the object.

The main problem, however, comes from assigning a static variable inside the constructor.  What is the behavior you wish?  Do you really need that every time you build a new SoapClient object, the static url is rewritten for *EVERY* instance of SoapClient?  Or would you need every client to store a different url (which sounds way better to me)?  In that case, I would just implement the url field as a regular field like someone else has suggested (just take out the `static` modifier from the field declaration)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways

```
public Login(String url) {
    Login.url = url;
}
```

But static varible is created only once in the class, so why you initialize it in the constructor. you can create another static method and initialize url in that.

```
public static void setUrl(String url) {
    Login.url = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A static variable is specific to the class, while a member variable is specific to an instance of the class. When we think to a SoapClient, you may think its URL is specific to each different instance of the class, as each SoapClient might have a different URL address.

This means it might be better to remove the static keyword from URL.
If you use url as a member variable, you have correctly intanstiated it.

If you want to use it as a static variable, use:

```
SoapClient.url = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken [from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):

> Sometimes, you want to have variables that are common to all objects.
>   This is accomplished with the static modifier. Fields that have the
>   static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class
>   variables. They are associated with the class, rather than with any
>   object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is
>   in one fixed location in memory. Any object can change the value of a
>   class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without
>   creating an instance of the class.

So You have two options:

```
public class SoapClient {
    private String url;

    public SoapClient(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public class SoapClient {
    private static String url = "http://stackoverflow.com";

    public SoapClient() {

    }
}
```